# How to display images in ul li randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have section of ul li with multiple images and i want to show 8 images first time and then want to show images radomly from all images.This is my ul li structure.

```
<ul id="randon-client">

<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li>                 
</ul>
```

Comment: _"want to show 8 images first time and then want to show images radomly from all images"_ What is "first time" ?

Comment: @guest271314, Initially on page load...

Comment: This may help: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/

Comment: Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L48x62t4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Show random each 3 secons

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
showRamdon()  
});

function showRamdon(){
      setTimeout(function() {

   $images   = $("#randon-client").find('img');
  total = $images.length;

  random = Math.floor(total  * Math.random()) + 1;
  $images.hide();
  $images.eq(random).show();
  showRamdon();
},1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="randon-client">

<li><img src="#" alt="brand1"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand2"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand3"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand4"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand5"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand6"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand7"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand8"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand9"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand10"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand11"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand12"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand13"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand14"></li> 
<li><img src="#" alt="brand15"></li>               
</ul>
```

Comment: I edit to test if this works. I change `brand9` with `brandNN` where NN is a incremental number. This code doesn't works.

Comment: I like the effect!! Congratulations. However, I think that OP doesn't ask for this. I think the best is the fiddle in the comments: https://jsfiddle.net/L48x62t4/1/ . I upvote you for the effect.